# C# maximize a form from another form

Tags: c#, forms, maximize-window

I am trying to do speech recognition for my application.  I have the Speech Recognition form (Form2) and my main form (Form1).  I want to find a way to maximize Form1 from Form2.  I have already learned about speech recognition and I don't need help with that, but any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated!

```
//Form1
public void Maximize()
{
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}


//Form2
private void Maximize_Form1()
{
Form1 form = new Form1();
form.Maximize();
}
```

I have tried the "Show" way, but that makes a whole new window.  Please Help.
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give a reference to the *existing* `Form1` instance to your `Form2` instance, so it can do `WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;` on it. For example:

```
class Form2 {

    private Form1 form1Ref;

    public void setForm1(Form1 f) { form1ref = f};

}
```

`Form1` would call `setForm1(this)` on the form2 instance, which could then use `form1ref` to maximize form1.

In your current code, you are creating a `new Form1` instance, which is totally independent from the previous instance.

Comment: Thank you! This is the first question that I have asked on this website and you were a lot of help!  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

you are using `this.WindowState` from From2, I would suggest you to pass a parameter to `Maximize()` method.

From Form2 when you execute the `Maximize()` method it considers Form2 in reference.

To pass the reference of Form1 you should send the object to Method and set the required property.

```
//Form1
public void Maximize(Form frmForm)
{
frmForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}


//Form2
private void Maximize_Form1()
{
Form1 form = new Form1();
form.Maximize(form);
}
```

Comment: Don't try to make another instance of `Form1` within `Form2`. You got to use same object of main form which was created.